# How to know the image sizes to design for hdpi, xhdpi, nodpi, etc

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to design custom images for my app but I'm confused how the image resolutions should differ in the different drawable folders.

Assuming I designed a 100px by 100px image for hdpi, what should be the resolution of xhdpi, xxhdpi, nodpi, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you should follow the 3:4:6:8:12:16 scaling ratio between the six generalized densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screens, all the different sizes should be:

```
36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density (launcher icon only; see note above)
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, thanks this helps but I can't accept it because of my low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that can help you !

http://hpics.li/5197929

let us know

Comment: Thanks, this helps too.